# Email notification for new friend requests on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications, facebook-friend-request

A few years ago, if I remember correctly, Facebook used to send emails regarding new friend requests. But now, in the notification settings, I can not find the setting to enable such email notifications.

So, my question is: has the friend requests email notification feature gone from FB? Or was it never present?

Answer (score 2):

it is still there if u are not getting it then u should go to your settings option there go inside -->
notification settings-->email--> and **choose the radio button against "All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from"**

[image]

Comment: That option is checked but still I am not getting any email regarding friend requests. Can you make sure you have emails in your inbox regarding FB friend requests?

Comment: @shivams yes i am sure, yesterday only i got an email regrading one friend request, u pls check ur primary email u have given for notification u should be getting notification there,__provided u have not unsubscribed__

Comment: @shivams, Is it possible that the emails are being filtered somehow (spams filter, etc.)? Or that you have unsubscribed?